# Add random number of microseconds to each index in a dataframe's datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe that uses a DateTime index. Due to the nature of the data, there are duplicate rows in the raw data that produce duplicate indices. I would like to add a random number of microseconds to each index to make them unique.

So, my index is currently:

```
2021-06-01 08:58:47+00:00
```

and I want it to be:

```
2021-06-01 08:58:47.011356+00:00
```

I have a column named TimeUTC which I used to create the index. I tried adding a random number of microseconds to it:

```
    df.index = df.index + datetime.timedelta(microseconds= random.randrange(0,1000000,1))
```

but that added the same number of microseconds to all rows. I had the same result when trying to use apply + lambda.

1. How can I add a random number of microseconds to each row's TimeUTC?
2. Can I do this directly to the index instead of updating TimeUTC and then reindexing?

Thank you.

Comment: If your data is ordered in time, one risk of adding random microseconds is that two rows with same original datetime may not be time ordered after adding random number, if the  first row get a bigger addition than the second one

Comment: Good point. I will reindex after doing the addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with `unit='us'` for microseconds, and an array of random number of the same length than the dataframe

```
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':range(10), 
    'TimeUTC':pd.to_datetime(['2021-10-01 00:00:00']*3+['2021-10-01 00:00:01']*5
                             +['2021-10-01 00:00:02']*2, utc=True)}
)

# set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(10)

# set the index from TimeUTC and add microseconds with to_timedelta
df.index = df['TimeUTC']+pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(1,1000000,len(df)),unit='us')

print(df)
                                  a                   TimeUTC
2021-10-01 00:00:00.345354+00:00  0 2021-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:00.760958+00:00  1 2021-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:00.881168+00:00  2 2021-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:01.443713+00:00  3 2021-10-01 00:00:01+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:01.617842+00:00  4 2021-10-01 00:00:01+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:01.105596+00:00  5 2021-10-01 00:00:01+00:00 
2021-10-01 00:00:01.533661+00:00  6 2021-10-01 00:00:01+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:01.927706+00:00  7 2021-10-01 00:00:01+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:02.299742+00:00  8 2021-10-01 00:00:02+00:00
2021-10-01 00:00:02.804337+00:00  9 2021-10-01 00:00:02+00:00
```

Note that adding random number may not conserve the time order of your dataframe, see in this case for the value a=5, the datetime index is lower than the previous two rows

Comment: Thank you, that took care of it quite nicely.

I sort the index after a variety of cleanup steps and so the issue you identified is taken care of.