# unrounding python timestamp data

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, formatting, timestamp

I have a large amount of timestamp data in a python dataframe formatted like this:
04/13/2017 09:00:00 PM

I need to 'unround' the timestamp data to run a statistical test later, by appending some random decimal point to each timestamp so that the timestamps are not the same, so that for instance it would be like:
04/13/2017 09:00:00.05 PM

If there were 2 timestamps with the same value, it should append different decimal values to them so that it ends up like, for instance:
04/13/2017 09:00:00.35 PM
04/13/2017 09:00:00.86 PM

Does anyone know the best way to do this in python?

Comment: You can use `timedelta` to add or subtract random number of milliseconds https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects and `randint` to pick the random amount to use when creating the timedelta https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: [Pandas Time deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html)

Comment: Does [Add random number of microseconds to each index in a dataframe's datetime index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443819/add-random-number-of-microseconds-to-each-index-in-a-dataframes-datetime-index) answer your question?

Comment: sounds a bit like an x-y problem - what are you actually trying to solve here? adding random numbers of microseconds does not guarantee the result to be duplicate-free btw.

Comment: @FObersteiner it's to do KS testing after to see if my data fits a certain distribution, recommended in this article to unround first: http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/Kim_W_MSOM_2014.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import random

formatted_timestamps = []

def format_timestamp(timestamp):
    formatted = timestamp + '.' + str(random.randint(0, 99)).zfill(2)
    while formatted in formatted_timestamps:
        formatted = timestamp + '.' + str(random.randint(0, 99)).zfill(2)
    formatted_timestamps.append(formatted)
    return formatted

print(format_timestamp('04/13/2017 09:00:00'))
print(format_timestamp('04/13/2017 09:00:00'))
```

Output (random):

`04/13/2017 09:00:00.90`

`04/13/2017 09:00:00.42`

Comment: thanks, if this process is followed, will the final output still be a timestamp?

Comment: It will be a string, not a timestamp